# How to create Menu bar with dynamic routes in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I want to create Menu bar with dynamic routes

This is my Menu bar code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 export class tab {

     path: string;
     active: boolean;
   }

 @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'business-tabs',
   templateUrl: '../views/business.tabs.html',
})


export class BusinessTabs {

  businessTabs :tab[]= [
 {
  path: 'businessProfile',
  active:true
}, 
  {
  path: 'contacts',
  active:false
}, {
  path: 'images',
  active: false
} ,{
  path: 'workingTime',
  active: false
 }
];
```

}

**business.tabs.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li  *ngFor="let btab of businessTabs"><a routerLink="{{btab.path}}"> {{btab.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I did route  config is

```
import {BusinessTermsConditionComponent} from './components/business-termscondition.component';

const BUSINESS_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'business',
   component: AdminComponent,
   children: [
      {
       path: 'businessProfile',
       component: BusinessProfileComponent,
      },
      {
       path: 'contacts',
       component: BusinessContactsComponent,
      },
      {
       path: 'images',
       component: BusinessImagesComponent,
      },
      {
      path: 'workingTime',
      component: BusinessWorkingTimeComponent,
     },

    ];

   @NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(BUSINESS_ROUTES)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class BusinessRoutingModule { }
```

So  I access routes like **localhost:3000/business/images**

In this page using selector **`<business-tabs></business-tabs>`** I am displaying menu bar.

My Problem is when I click another menu like contacts, working time then it naviges the route **localhost:3000/business/images/workingtime** But this is not route thats why it's showing error.

**Images table template is**

```
  <div class="box box-default">
   <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <business-tabs></business-tabs>
  </div>
 </div> 
Here I am displaying menubar.
```

Please help me to create this menu bar with routes

Comment: in businessTabs object there is no key called title. Can give your github link

Comment: mistakly I wrote that

Comment: provide your correct code

Comment: it's not possible to share my github link

Comment: atleast add proper code in the question

Comment: I add some more code .images template can you please once check it

Comment: your code works fine. can u plz reproduce issue in plunk

Comment: Your paths must start with a `/`.

Comment: that is not creating any problem for me

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you importing `OnInit` when you did not use it.

Second you used `Routes` without importing it, same case for `NgModule` and `RouterModule`, import them by adding:

`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

Also, you should import all the components you added to your `BUSINESS_ROUTES` Routes object(that is `AdminComponent`, `BusinessProfileComponent`, `BusinessContactsComponent`, `BusinessImagesComponent` and `BusinessWorkingTimeComponent`)

At the end do not forget to import the `BusinessRoutingModule` itself to your app's main module's imports. (i.e: `imports: [..., ..., ..., BusinessRoutingModule]`)

EDITED:

I see another major issue, you did not use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

try to insert it as follows

```
<div class="box box-default">
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
<business-tabs></business-tabs>
</div>

<!-- INSERTED HERE -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag will let angular display the desired routes just below the tag.

Comment: I impoted all modules in my BusinessRoutingModule, the routes are working fine, thats not issue, I want to navigate routes from menu bar

Comment: My code working fine, My doubt is navigation of routes in menu bar, Now I got it ,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figure out my issue 
 that is

**Before**

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li  *ngFor="let btab of businessTabs"><a routerLink="{{btab.path}}">    {{btab.title}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Now**

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li  *ngFor="let btab of businessTabs"><a routerLink="/business/{{btab.path}}"> {{btab.title}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```